# How to bring the button down in a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have buttons and select dropdown in a popup. but for some reason, I cannot move the button to the position that's below the dropdown.

I've tried putting them in different table rows but it didn't help.

Here's my code

```js
$(".form").button();
$("#popup").dialog({
  title: "Test",
  modal: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="overflow:scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <select style="width:100px;">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
      </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="button" class="form" value="Save">
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean like https://jsfiddle.net/smo4sjbv/ this?

Comment: Tables shouldn't be used for layout purposes. They are for tabular data.

Comment: @Scott what about using them for forms?

Comment: Nope.. that's still *layout*. Unless your'e spitting out rows of data, or creating an HTML email, there's no need for tables. @RudiUrbanek has the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `<td></td>`

```js
$(".form").button();
$("#popup").dialog({
  title: "Test",
  modal: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="overflow:scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select style="width:100px;">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="button" class="form" value="Save">
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually no need for you to use tables just float them and clear the float alignment on following button.

```js
$(".form").button();
$("#popup").dialog({
  title: "Test",
  modal: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="overflow:scroll;">
      <select style="width:100px; float:left;">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" class="form" value="Save" style="float:left; clear:both;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing `<td>` tag within `<tr>`

```js
$(".form").button();
$("#popup").dialog({
  title: "Test",
  modal: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="overflow:scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select style="width:100px;">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>7</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="form" value="Save">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotta throw some  in there!

```js
$(".form").button();
$("#popup").dialog({
  title: "Test",
  modal: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="overflow:scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <select style="width:100px;">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="form" value="Save">
    </tr>
   </td>
  </table>
</div>
```